# Positive/negative octupole moment of nuclei?

Tags: nuclear-physics, multipole-expansion

Does octupole moment of nuclear charge distribution show any positive/negative character, like the quadrupole moment does? Quadrupole moment has prolate and oblate types, but what about characterization of octupole moment?

Comment: Ana please give a link to the octupole moment of nuclear charge distribution. Good question.

Comment: You might enter the literature via [this measurement of octupole deformation in radium](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature12073).  I remember that there's some magic in going from the five-element traceless rank-2 quadrupole tensor to the quadrupole moment, which somehow ends you up with two quadrupole parameters, one of which is the "quadrupole moment" and the other which people can usually forget about. I assume that being careful about octupole moments is similarly tricky.

Comment: Sorry I won't be able to point to some particular source reagrding octupole moment of nuclei. I had been reading 'Introductory Nuclear Physics by Samuel Wong' wherein the author has talked about the moments and corresponding nuclear shapes. That made me wonder if the prolate and oblate shapes indicate a positive or negative quadrupole moment, then would there be a similar argument to explain the octupole vibrations of nuclei?

Comment: @rob so the tensor leads to the (+) and (-) in the observed quadrupole moment?