# If the dipole moment is not unique, how can the probability of absorption depend on the angle between the dipole moment and the electric-field?

Tags: quantum-optics, dipole-moment

For systems with non-zero net charge, the dipole moment depends on the choice of origin (see [Does the dipole moment depend on the choice of origin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418785/does-the-dipole-moment-depend-on-the-choice-of-origin)). How then, can the probability of emission/absorption of light by an atom depend on the angle between the dipole moment and the electric-field component of the light wave?

Comment: the net charge of an atom is zero, no?  And in any case classical modeling is no good for atoms, it has to be a photon interacting which has no electric field components, just energy and spin.

Comment: Atoms are neutral. Could you clarify your question? @annav stimulated absorption can be evaluated within a semiclassical approximation where photons do not appear.

Comment: Consider a charged atom or system of atoms. Single photon emitters, for example point defects in crystals, emit/absorb photons with highest probability when the incoming/outgoing photon direction is perpendicular to the transition dipole moment. Just doesn't make sense if the dipole moment is ill-defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the dipole moment depend on the choice of origin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418785/does-the-dipole-moment-depend-on-the-choice-of-origin)

Comment: As Ken says, we could be calculating the interaction with an ion so the proposed duplicate is not actually a duplicate.